# Checking input format

Tags: java

I have a program I'm writing for class, and I'm stuck on the very last part.  Here's what it requests, and what I'm stuck at:

> Display an error if the file does not exist or the format is
>   incorrect.

The formatting of the input is along the lines of:

> Name;Service;Price;Date
>
> or
>
> Bob Smith;Dinner;52.35;04-01-2014

And my code so far:

```
package school;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class HotelSales{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
            // I assume the format check would go here?
            String[] array = new String[48];
            double conferenceTotal = 0;
            double dinnerTotal = 0;
            double lodgingTotal = 0;
            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                array = line.split(";");
                if(array[1].equals("Conference")) {
                    conferenceTotal += Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
                } else if(array[1].equals("Dinner")) {
                    dinnerTotal += Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
                } else if(array[1].equals("Lodging")) {
                    lodgingTotal += Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The totals for the sales are: \n");
            System.out.printf("Conference Total: $%-5.2f\n", conferenceTotal);
            System.out.printf("Dinner Total: $%-5.2f\n", dinnerTotal);
            System.out.printf("Lodging Total: $%-5.2f\n", lodgingTotal);

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
            bw.write("The totals for the sales are: ");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Conference Total: $" + String.format("%-5.2f",conferenceTotal));
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Dinner Total: $" + String.format("%-5.2f",dinnerTotal));
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Lodging Total: $" + String.format("%-5.2f",lodgingTotal));

            br.close();
            bw.close();

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) { //And that this is the proper catch right?
            System.out.print("Wrong input file format.\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print("Sorry, the file was not found.\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Oops! I/O Exception.\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: so what's the problem? You seem to be catching the exceptions and printing reasonable error messages for them.

Comment: I can't tell if it's actually catching what I want it to.  I would have assumed that it would throw my InputMismatchException and show the "Wrong input file format.\n", but it doesn't show that.

Comment: I think you're missing a catch for `NumberFormatException`

Comment: What I'm expecting to catch is something along the lines of an incorrect input file containing: "Bob Smith,Dinner,27.64,04-11-2014" where it's commas instead of semi-colons, or something to that effect.  That wouldn't be accomplished with NumberFormatException would it?

Comment: probably not. You should check that your `split` operation returned the correct number of elements, and that each one conforms to the format you're expecting.

Comment: That's where I'm stuck. I don't know how to do that. As it is right now, it should be giving 4 elements (name;service;price;date) or is it 3 (3 ;'s)? That, and I don't know how to check if it's conforming to the right format.

Comment: If your input file is not separated by ;'s, then when you attempt to Double.parseDouble(array[2]), you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or a NullPointerException because your array will be of size 1.

Comment: @MikeN Any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        String [] array = line.split(";");
        if ( array.length != 4 ) {
            throw new InputMismatchException( "Invalid ... blah blah, expected 4 elements, found " + array.length );
        }
        try {
            if(array[1].equals("Conference")) {
                conferenceTotal += Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
            } else if(array[1].equals("Dinner")) {
                dinnerTotal += Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
            } else if(array[1].equals("Lodging")) {
                lodgingTotal += Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
            }
        } catch ( NumberFormatException nfe ) {
            throw new InputMismatchException( nfe );
        }
    }
```

and remove the line:

```
String[] array = new String[48];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is not separated by ;'s, then when you attempt to Double.parseDouble(array[2]), you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or a NullPointerException because your array will be of size 1.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    array = line.split(";");
    if (array.length != 4)
    {
        throw new InputMismatchException("Invalid ... blah blah, expected 4 elements, found " + array.length);
    }
    try
    {
        if (array[1].equals("Conference"))
        {
            conferenceTotal += Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
        }
        else if (array[1].equals("Dinner"))
        {
            dinnerTotal += Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
        }
        else if (array[1].equals("Lodging"))
        {
            lodgingTotal += Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
        }
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptione aioobe)
    {
        throw new InputMismatchException(aioobe);
    }
```